# Monitor connections instances in a C++ program

Tags: c++, multithreading, modbus, rs485

In my project I'm using `libmodbus`

I have a thread that uses a `modbus_t` connection to check status of multiple `RTU` slaves.

I want to create another thread that checks for the status of the modbus connection.

If the connection fails the first thread should be stopped.

Any idea or approach can help.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need another thread for that? Couldn't the first thread stop itself, when it detects an error or a [timeout](https://libmodbus.org/docs/v3.1.6/modbus_set_response_timeout.html)?

Comment: I have a main class that starts the slaves check thread, and it must detect if the bus is still fine, if not it stops the work and continue to monitor it so if it goes back (for example getting the RTU cable back) it should detect that and restart the thread.

Comment: OK so you just want to pause the main thread, not kill/exit/join. I guess you have some data that you TX and/or RX to or between your modbus slaves... it's all a bit vague. And are you asking how to transfer data between threads? Or how to distinguish "bus failure" from "slave failure"?

Comment: Yes I want a thread for RX/TX on slaves, and other for "bus failure" check. If bus failed kill the RX/TX thread, then keeps monitoring the bus, if "bus passed" start the RX/TX thread again